# Programmatic data in .NET Winforms DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm getting a weird behavior with a datagrid.  No matter what I do, it's ordering the columns arbitrarily and adding all the columns in the objects.

I'm using .NET 3.5, with a winforms datagrid.  The Datasource is set at runtime, not design time.  I've tried defining the columns in the GDI, but it ignores the order.  Even if I only define one item, it displays the every public property on the list I pass in.

```
List<EventLog> events = service.GetEvents();
EventLogList.DataSource = events;
EventLogList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
EventLogList.Refresh();
```

EventLog is an object generated by Linq2Sql.  It passes back a view.  The grid always shows every column, regardless of what I do to the columns object in the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property set to false?

Comment: It was, but I was setting it to false after setting the datasource not before.

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoGenerateColumns = false BEFORE setting the datasource....